# How best to make glue/resin

Tags: modeling

I wanted to model the inside of this lightbulb screw, specifically the red glue (or resin) and uneven edges/mottled look it has... any ideas on how to do that? I've modeled a rough shape for the area where it dips from the rim but not sure whats the best way to get an 'organic' look...

Any help?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I approached this by creating a custom texture. First I Marked three seams in the base mesh <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> > Mark Seam.

[image: Mark Seams]

Then unwrapped it. By selecting all of the vertices and pressing <kbd>U</kbd> > Unwrap. I scaled the UV Map larger because I was only interested in the area I applied the custom resin texture to.

[image: Unwrap]

Then exported the UV layout and in an image editor created a custom texture. Of course turned off the UV Layout before saving the finished texture.

[image: Custom Texture]

[image: Nodes]

[image: Final]

Comment: You are welcome. And thank you for inspiring me to ask another question about the broken glass!